# Android Studio: set as a Project

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm new on Android Studio, and I'm still learning to importing libs and modules.
The thing is I have created my project as usual but in some point I lost the "project" gradle file and no I have only modules.
[image]

I wonder why none of gradle files have the "Project" word. In fact I'm interesting in the file build.gradle (Module:Swipe) to (Project:Swipe)

## Question

How can I set the file build.gradle (Module:Swipe) changes to (Project:Swipe)

Comment: So, what's your question?

Comment: @AnggrayudiH I have updated the question.

Comment: try to change the view of your files from Android to project

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question... 
It seems like you are missing the Project gradle file. I dont know what caused that. 
To add a new one, just copy one from another project and edit it (it needs to be located on the project folder)

*Maybe it will be easier on the project pane. see here how to change to project panel:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4nm5.jpg